# SQLite constraint exception on empty table when running rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, rspec

I'm having a weird problem with my Rspec test suite. All tests that insert data into a table that has a unique constraint fail. Running the failing tests individually by specifying the line number works as expected.

To investigate the issue I printed the number of rows in that table before inserting the data that is causing the constraint exception and it reports that the table is empty.

There is no `before :all` in any file at all.

I'm using DatabaseCleaner and, except for this issue, it seems that the cleaning is working.

This e.g. doesn't work when running the whole file:

```
describe User

  # ...

  describe '#follow_location' do
    let(:user) { Factory(:user) }
    let(:location) { Factory(:location) }

    it 'should raise when trying to follow an already followed location' do
      puts LocationFollowship.count  # => 0
      user.followed_locations << location  # exception raised
      lambda {
        user.follow_location location
      }.should raise_error User::AlreadyFollowingLocation
    end
  end

  # …

end
```

**EDIT:**
I was able to track it down. It has to do with Rails using a cached statement. Calling `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.clear_cache!` makes it work. But adding this snippet in spec_helper.rb causes an SQLite exception `cannot use a closed statement`.

Comment: can you show us your factories? :) maybe you added an id field

Comment: They don't set any explicit ids at all.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. In addition, the Ruby interpreter would segfault under certain conditions when I tried to investigate it (probably caused by SQLite).

I have a unique index declared, like so:

```
add_index(:table, [:column1, :column2], unique: true)
```

Adding the following uniqueness constraint to the model (in addition to the existing index in the migration) made the issue go away:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :column1, scope: :column2
```